# Materialized Set Up Wizard like native in Lollipop

Tags: android, material-design, setup-wizard

How Do I create `Materialized Set Up Wizard` (Steps View)

Actually, In my application, I need to ask the user some information in the beginning. Like Google asks users when they first launch the phone.

`Step 1:` Info (Next)

`Step 2:` More Info (Back and Next)

`Step 3:` Review (Back and Submit)

Like **Lollipop's** Set Up Wizard

[image]

But I have many `TextView(s) and EditText(s)` in each and every Screen, this is what i exactly need, should I need to customize it as per my requirement, or is there any official lib to use ?

Comment: Not sure if this lib meets your requirement https://github.com/matrixxun/ProductTour. Modify according to your needs

Comment: @Raghunandan thank you so much, exactly what i was looking for .. thank you so much

Comment: @Raghunandan I also want to materialize my complete app, and widgets i have to use: Edittext, checkboxes, radio buttons, spinner, pickers and other available controls.. which lib you would recommend me ? and i want to support minimum api 9

Comment: Use AppCompat and you can style your widgets to get a look feel of material

Comment: @Raghunandan I have tried earlier but i am not getting same look and feel of material (in pre-lollipop devices, like: Dialog), can you show me any demo in which i can check where i am doing mistake ?